# "..." pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation

I saw something like this, but everyone answered "and so on" or "et cetera." However, I am using it to omit words from a quotation. For example:

> Joe said "foo ... bar"

How would I pronounce this?

Comment: It has no pronunciation.

Comment: In quoted speech it usually represents a pause.  In a quotation from some written material it usually represents text that was omitted.

Comment: It's known as "[ellipsis](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ellipsis)".

Comment: well yeah I know that. I was asking how to pronounce it when used for omitting text, but apparently you don't pronounce it.

Comment: See above. ellipsis

Comment: You pronounce it by pausing.

Comment: Joe said: "foo, yada-yada, bar."